# Using ELMAH inside my asp.net mvc 4 & MVC5 web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, error-handling, asp.net-mvc-5, elmah

I have two asp.net mvc web applications; asp.net mvc4 and asp.net mvc5 , they are both deployed under iis7 on two separate VMs.

now i am currently facing problems when un-handled exceptions are raised,,, because users will be re-directed to the Error view inside the shared folder under the view section. and i am unable to know exactly the exception details..

so i have read about using the ELMAH tool which will automatically logs all the UN-handled exceptions. but my question is that what are the steps that i need to follow to configure the tool inside myC application ?

second question; will ELMAH works on asp.net vmc4 and asp.net mvc5 in the same way?

Third question. now i have custom error set to `<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" />` inside my live asp.net mvc web application, since i do not want end users to be exposed to the technical details about any exception, so when using elmah should i set the custom error to be no ?
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1) Just install Elmah from Nuget. That will enable it with the default configuration to save exceptions to an XML file

2) Yes, it should work both in MVC4 and 5

3) No, you can leave it as it is. The Elmah page is available locally only by default. Users will be still redirected to your Error page, and you can use the elmah URL locally to access the actual error information.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but how i will be able to view the error logs ?

Comment: By default elmah expose them in the following URL http://yourapp/elmah.axd. Which must be accesible only locally. It store the data in an xml file but there are extension to store to database or wherever it suits you.

Comment: ok now i access the elmah using the following URL https://localhost:444/myapp/elmah.axd, but i got "no error found",, although i intentionally made an un-handle exception to my application ... can you adivce

Comment: Uhm, that have happened to me from time to time. Usually because lack of permissions to access the database, or the database not being created properly. I suggest going through the following guide to check you don't have missed anything: http://www.dotnetspan.com/2015/01/integrate-and-setup-elmah-in-aspnet-mvc.html Check the web.config specially

Comment: but i am confused now,, will elmah log the errors inside the database ? or it will log them inside a file ... i did not add any database or tables to store the errors ...

Comment: In a file. Still you need to check rights. I only said that I used to have the same problem when I used a database and have those problems with it. Not that those are yours :)

Comment: now i think i did a mistake i install the elmah from the following link https://www.nuget.org/packages/elmah/ and not the one that is used for mvc from this link https://www.nuget.org/packages/Elmah.MVC/ coludl this cause the issue,, as the application pool user have right access to the whole iss folder...

Comment: Yes that is probably for just asp .net. Try the second link and see what happens :)

Comment: now installed the mvc version of the elmah and then i copied the three .dll files from my visual studio to my iis ,, and i did the required modifications to the web.confog,, but now if i try to access the localhost:44/myapp/elmah.axd the browser will keeps loading then i will get 404 page not found error....